# Can you use an APFS-formatted Mac with a pre-APFS Apple Time Capsule?

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule, hfs+, high-sierra, apfs

I'm thinking of upgrading to macOS High Sierra, however I'm a bit cautious with the APFS, also because it just came out.

**Are you able to use Time Machine on a Mac with APFS-formatted disks with an Apple Time Capsule that uses an HDD an older file system (HFS+)**

My guess is it won't work so you have to also manually convert the Apple Time Capsule to APFS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having an APFS-formatted system backed up to an HFS+ Time Machine/Time Capsule disk is actually the currently intended use case.  The current version of Time Machine supports APFS only as a source disk, not as a destination.  In fact, if you format your Time Machine backup disk to APFS, Time Machine will re-format it back to HFS+ before using that disk.  This was discussed in WWDC 2016, and [appears](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/deep-dive/time-machine-and-apfs-need-know/) to [still be true](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/6fog42/time_machine_and_apfs/dmxt7sl/).

APFS does not support directory hardlinks, a feature of the filesystem used by Time Machine.  Until Time Machine is rebuilt to take advantage of APFS features (like snapshots) instead of hard links, APFS won't be usable as a destination disk.

Also, I personally just backed up my APFS laptop to my usual HFS+ backup disk via Time Machine, so there is some empirical validation.

Comment: Thanks for your help and providing the links and your own experience !

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use a normal Time Capsule that is not APFS-formatted with APFS-formatted disks.

> APFS and Time Machine
>
> You don't need to change any Time Machine settings to back up
>   APFS-formatted disks. Any Time Machine share points must be shared
>   over SMB instead of AFP.

Source: [Apple.com](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208018)

This applies to Apple’s TimeCapsules as well. They are just network attached hard drives with Wi-Fi routers made by Apple.

Comment: Thanks what about that "use SMB instead of AFP" ?

Comment: You may need to remove your Time Machine's disk and re-add it so macOS will mount it correctly.

Comment: what do you mean by remove ? Sorry but I'm not very familiar with configuring the Time Capsule.

Comment: Also, your very useful link and quote above, thanks again, only mention Time MACHINE but not Time CAPSULE. A time machine could also be a third party external SSD drive that someone configures as a Time Machine, in that case the "you don't have to change anything approach from Apple" makes sense, but Apple's Time CAPSULE comes with a hard-drive, at least the one I bought in 2016.

Comment: To remove a Time Machine disk go to **System Preferences > Time Machine > Add or Remove Backup Disk...**. Select your disk, click 'Remove Disk' and add it back again.

Comment: @MFJC does this answer your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66204/discussion-between-oa-and-mfjc).

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't but thanks. Like I said above in my other comment, a user can create a Time Machine with a SSD drive from any third party vendor if they want. And I think Apple is referring to this by saying you don't need to change anything to ones' Time Machine settings (the software). I am referring to the Apple Time CAPSULE (hardware), that has a hard drive in it, and so something that will be in HFS until (and if I need to) I convert it to APFS.